# Steam downloads keep switching

Tags: steam

I’m trying to download some games on steam, but everytime I leave it on to download the game downloading keeps switching with another one. I want to download one specific game first, so I’d there any way to prioritize that one?

Comment: You can move them up using the 'Download Now' button on the Downloads screen, but I assume from your post they don't behave accordingly?

Comment: If what Joachim said isn't working, just hit play for the game you want to download and it will force steam to download the game so you can play it.

Comment: Make sure you have enough diskspace. Usually game size * 2 is needed to properly install a game.

Comment: I would recommend to change the downlaod settings for oyur ther games to only downlaod/update when played. There is no need to keep downloading them all the time

Comment: After the download switches off the one you wanted it to complete, is there any kind of error message associated to the one that stopped downloading prematurely?